# Blur top and bottom of multiline label

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have multiline label (for example 100 lines) which text is scrolling from bottom to top, something like movie credits. I would like to blur 10% of the top and bottom portions of that label so that text which is entering and leaving is blurred. How can I achieve that? I tried to stick some elements over that positions and blur them but that did not work.

Comment: What does it mean `doesn't work`? Can you provide code and screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen blurrying, but usually the text is fading. Here's an example how you could do fading: Create an overlay pane with a linear gradient that goes from background color -> transparent -> background color. Like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(
                "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. ");
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Pane overlay = new Pane();
        overlay.setMouseTransparent(true);

        Stop[] stops = new Stop[] { new Stop(0.0, Color.WHITE), new Stop(0.25, Color.TRANSPARENT), new Stop(0.75, Color.TRANSPARENT), new Stop(1.0, Color.WHITE) };
        LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);
        overlay.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(linearGradient, null, null)));

        root.getChildren().addAll(textArea, overlay);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

If you insist on blurring, you could use the [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot%28javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) function, create a snapshot of the text, blur the image and put it on top of the text.